# Replaying event store

Tags: projection, event-driven, event-driven-design, event-stream, event-stream-processing

I have event store on Service A connected to event stream, and Service B is building projection from events in that stream. Since event stream size is limited events are kept there for a limited amount of time.

In case when I want to rebuild projection on Service B, are there some patterns for how Service B can signal Service A to replay those events? What are the best practices for doing it?